# ng-repeat and custom directive transclude trouble

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote my own directive, here some code:

```
app.directive 'rateHighlight', ($timeout) ->
{
restrict: 'E'
template: require './view.html'
scope: {
  value: '=value'
},
transclude: true,
controller: [
  '$rootScope'
  '$scope'
  '$element'
  '$transclude'
  '$timeout'
  ($root, $scope, $element, $transclude, $timeout) ->
    $scope.chart = $element.find('.content')
    $scope.chart.append($transclude());
    $scope.$watch 'value', (newValue, oldValue) ->
      if newValue > oldValue
        $scope.chart.addClass('up')
        $timeout(() ->
          $scope.chart.removeClass('up')
        , 2500)
      if newValue < oldValue
        $scope.chart.addClass('down')
        $timeout(() ->
          $scope.chart.removeClass('down')
        , 2500)
]
}
```

View.html looks very simple:

```
<span class="rate badge content"></span>
```

And I use my directive like this:

```
<rate-highlight value="rate.high"></exchange-rate-highlight>
```

`rate` object is object from `parent` directive (root scope). It works pretty fine, but I face problem when I try to use it in `ng-repeat` loop. In two words I have a main parent directive with root scope. Scope shares its `rate` object with children directives and we get such schema :

```
<parent>
  <innerCustomDirective ng-repeat="rate in charts">
    <oneMoreInnerDirective>
      <rateHighlight value="rate.high"></rateHighlight>
      <rateHighlight value="rate.low"></rateHighlight>
    </oneMoreInnerDirective>
  <innerCustomDirective/>
</parent>
```

It builds needed structure. But I can see only one last block of `<rateHighlight>` directives on my screen. And it uses `rate` object from the first step of `ng-repeat` (`charts[0]`). Hope you will help! Sorry for my bad english.

**RESOLVED!**

There is something strange with transcluding. I change my template html to

```
<span class="rate badge content" ng-transclude></span>
```

and remove this line from controller:

```
$scope.chart.append($transclude());
```

And now everything is working fine.

Comment: use not value="rate.high" , but value="rootScope.rates[ng_repeat_index].high"

Comment: Does the `innerCustomDirective` use isolate scope? If so it could be fighting the inherited scope created by the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! But the problem was in transcuding @georgeawg